# Tkinter Scrollbar inactive untill the window is manually resized

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

The scrollbar activates only when the window is rezised, despite reconfiguring the scrollregion everytime a widget(Button in this case) is added.

```
class Editor:

    
    def __init__(self,master):
         
        self.master = master
        self.master.resizable(True,False)
        
        self.edit_frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.edit_frame.pack(fill="none") 
        self.elem_frame = tk.Frame(self.master,width=700)
        self.elem_frame.pack(fill="y", expand=1)

        self.my_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.elem_frame, width = 700)
        self.my_canvas.pack(side = "left", fill="both", expand=1)

        my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.elem_frame, orient = "vertical", command =self.my_canvas.yview)
        my_scrollbar.pack(side = "right",fill="y")

        self.my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)

        self.my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.movescroll )


        self.second_frame = tk.Frame(self.my_canvas, bg = "black", width=700)

        self.my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.second_frame, anchor="nw")

                        
        self.naz = Nazioni()
        paesi = [*self.naz.iso3]
        print(paesi)
        self.comb_paese = ttk.Combobox(self.edit_frame, value = paesi)
        self.comb_paese.current(1)
        
        
        self.kwordvar= tk.StringVar()
        entry_keyword = tk.Entry(self.edit_frame, textvariable=self.kwordvar)
        entry_keyword.bind("<FocusOut>", self.callback)
         
        
        writer = tk.Text(self.edit_frame)
        
        
        self.edit_frame.pack(side="left") 
        writer.pack()
        self.comb_paese.pack()
        entry_keyword.pack() 
                  

    def callback(self, *args):
         kword = self.kwordvar.get()
         self.colonnarisultati(kword) 
  
    def colonnarisultati(self, keyword):
       
        
       #TROVA IL VALORE CODICE ISO A 3CHAR IN BASE ALLA NAZIONE NEL COMBOBOX
       p = self.comb_paese.get()
       paese = self.naz.iso3[p]
       ricerca = Ricerca(paese, keyword)
       """ 
       for label in self.elem_frame.winfo_children():
            label.destroy()
       """
       self.count = 0
       print("ciao")
       for x in ricerca.listaricerca:
            
           tit = str(x['titolo']).lstrip("<h4>").rstrip("</h4>")
           print(tit) 
           self.elementotrovato(tit,self.count)
           self.count +=1 
       self.my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.my_canvas.bbox("all"))
    
                
       
    def movescroll(self, *args):
        self.my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.my_canvas.bbox("all"))
           



    def elementotrovato(self, testobottone, conta):

          Bott_ecoifound = tk.Button(self.second_frame, text = testobottone,width = 100 ,height = 30, font = ("Helvetica", 12, "bold"), wraplength=200, justify="left")
          print("CIAONE")
          
          Bott_ecoifound.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
          self.my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.my_canvas.bbox("all"))
```

The last method is the one adding button to the scrollable frame.
After the window is manually resized, no matter if back to its original size, the scrollbar activates and works fine.

Comment: Immediately after adding a Button, `.bbox("all")` is not going to return an updated value - because Tkinter hasn't had a chance to calculate the Button's size yet.  You need to call `.update_idletasks()` (on any widget or window) to force that calculation, before setting the `scrollregion`.

Comment: You need to bind `<Configure>` on `self.second_frame` instead of `self.my_canvas` because it is `self.second_frame` get resized when adding items to it, not `self.my_canvas`.